# Why does C++ vector size start out at 4294967296 yet the debugger reads it as 0?

Tags: c++

From this sample code:

```
    vector<int> v;

    // cout << v.size() << endl;         // prints 0
    // cout << v.size() - 1 << endl;     // prints 

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
        cout << v[i] << endl;
```

### I got an out of range error. A few questions:

- Why did the code go into the for loop?
- Why did the 2nd cout print 4294967295?
- Why is the 1st cout printing 0 when it's actually using 4294967296? The Visual Studio 2015 debugger is showing 0 for some reason.

Comment: `std::size_t` is an unsigned integer type, so `0 - 1` causes an integer underflow

Comment: This question is one day to late …

Comment: Why so many downvotes?  Would like to learn the culture of the voting.

Comment: Regarding Downvotes: This question is easily answered with existing resources demonstrating a lack of research. This is also probably why none of the answers have received upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

> Why did the 2nd cout print 4294967295?

Because `std::vector::size_type` is unsigned. Negative numbers are not representable by unsigned integers. When you subtract one from an unsigned integer of value zero, the number "wraps around" and will become the largest value representable by that type. For a 32 bit integer, that number is 2<sup>32</sup> - 1, which is 4294967295.

More generally, if the result of a calculation is not representable by the unsigned type, the result will be congruent (with the actual, unrepresentable result) modulo the largest representable value + 1.

> Why did the go into the for loop?

Because 0 is less than 4294967295.

> Why is the 1st cout printing 0 when it's actually using 4294967296? The Visual Studio 2015 debugger is showing 0 for some reason.

The size is actually 0. 4294967296 is a value too large to be representable by the `std::vector::size_type` on your system.

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop condition, `vals.size() - 1` will have its result be of an `unsigned type` aka `std::vector<int>::size_type` because that is the [***common type***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) in the expression.

You have in effect:

```
std::vector<int>::size_type(0) - std::vector<int>::size_type(1)
```

which will wrap around and produce a very large number...

**Solution:** You can use some little maths theory to achieve this thing (move the `-1` to the other side of the inequality):

```
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < v.size(); i++)
     cout << v[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why it's 4294967295?

Answer (score 0):

`v.size()` returns a `size_t` which is an unsigned type. Once you subtract one from that - given that its current value is 0 - it wraps around to become a bit pattern representing a large positive number.

Answer (score 0):

The size of vector is unsigned type, it is the same if you write

```
size_t x = -1;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

and if you assign -1 to it will be transfered to the maximum value of size_t

Answer (score -3):

I think I found the problem.  size() returns an unsigned number.  So subtracting 1 from it in the for loop and the cout makes it loop around to the largest number of that data size.  Not sure why it's 4294967295 though.